# How to check the input value is not empty spaces?

Tags: php

I'm using PHP in my project and when any form is submitted I need to check if the input it not empty, so I use something like this:

```
if(empty($myVar)) {
    echo "Error";
} else {
    echo "success";
}
```

But this doesn't seem to be working as I want, so If the user enter empty space like "    " so between the quotation is nothing but emptiness, but still PHP showing success message instead of error message.

I used isset($var) also, but its the samething, not working as I need.

What could be the problem? and How to solve it?

Comment: `empty(trim($myVar))` and you are fine. And since we are in it-world you mean more: `eyesight emptiness`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`trim`](http://php.net/trim) function, which removes spaces in the beginning and in the end of a string:

```
if(empty(trim($myVar))) {
    echo "Error"
} else {
    echo "success";
}
```

Comment: Thank So much, you saved my day :)
But I have a quick question, why empty function is not useful in this state? why it doesn't count space as a real character?
Or what exactly is happening in this function?

Comment: Here's a manual page http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php#refsect1-function.empty-returnvalues It describes which values are considered empty

Comment: @Maohammed Hayder  Very important and helpfull tables  http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

Answer (score 3):

```
echo empty(trim($myVar)) ? 'Error' : 'success';
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to `trim` all fields from `$_POST`, use the following:

```
$_POST = array_map("trim", $_POST);
```

Then you can just check with `empty()`.

But this is only useful if you have a couple of fields. For just one, you should follow the direct way with `empty(trim($var))`

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you should first trim the $myVar before checking the emptyness as follows

```
if(empty(trim($myVar))) {
    echo "Error";
} else {
    echo "success";
}
```

What this will do is will remove any leading or trailing whitespaces from variable $myVar and then check if the variable is empty or not.